# Why my Heroku app is not loading any data while opening in other devices even though my database is connected?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku

I recently deployed my NodeJS application on heroku from git, it deployed successfully and running on my local machine without any fail. But when opening on other devices, the data stored in Database is not loading up. I also allowed my atlas IP whitelist to access from all devices. I couldn't able to find the mistake.
Here is my App.js file,

```
    require("dotenv").config();
    
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const path = require("path");
    
    const app = express();
    
    const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
    const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
    const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/category");
    const productRoutes = require("./routes/product");
    const orderRoutes = require("./routes/order");
    const stripeRoutes = require("./routes/stripepayment");
    
    //Middle wares
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(cors());
    
    // Database connection
    mongoose
      .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("DB CONNECTED");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR", err);
      });
    
    //Routes
    app.use("/api", authRoutes);
    app.use("/api", userRoutes);
    app.use("/api", categoryRoutes);
    app.use("/api", productRoutes);
    app.use("/api", orderRoutes);
    app.use("/api", stripeRoutes);
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      //Set static folder
      app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
      });
    }
    
    //server
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 7000, "0.0.0.0", () => {
      console.log(`App is running at 7000`);
    });
```

Here is my Heroku log for this application

```
    2021-12-06T09:52:16.430092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/2.e7166e2e.chunk.css" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=25aa7dc1-acf3-4b9b-af2a-f4ffe0948dc5 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:16.450752+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.2bcfeed7.chunk.css" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=c565960a-7fa9-4aa9-8498-564ff9411eb6 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:16.741237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.674c3ee4.chunk.js" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=20ff86ee-d3fa-44d0-b29c-6fbbb63869ef fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:16.785859+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.53d21ff9.chunk.js" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=637d2007-8195-41ed-be1b-1da51fb7a08f fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:19.384480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/weblogo.png" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=15681d65-512d-407c-b8cd-8b7743ce2e4b fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:20.252200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=77dff797-2561-4136-b3cc-75ff247c9129 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:20.596998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=a9d544d3-8be0-4475-89d5-f30700320afe fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:21.557993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=a8cb8aee-8146-4df0-899f-d812227d1bfb fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:21.871712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=ff819f69-c546-4b40-9344-545f2377f7d2 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:22.353954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=dde45574-f317-4771-b057-ea66804efbb6 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T09:52:22.670464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=shop-spot.herokuapp.com request_id=0a75d338-4f23-4cbc-bc31-5d0ced8bd8a8 fwd="157.48.225.94" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
    2021-12-06T10:06:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user srinivasmoparthi17@gmail.com
    2021-12-06T10:07:07.033792+00:00 app[api]: Release v38 created by user srinivasmoparthi17@gmail.com
    2021-12-06T10:07:07.033792+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 79228b19 by user srinivasmoparthi17@gmail.com
    2021-12-06T10:07:07.300298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2021-12-06T10:07:07.315781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2021-12-06T10:07:08.370421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2021-12-06T10:07:08.613075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2021-12-06T10:07:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2021-12-06T10:07:12.863949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2021-12-06T10:07:14.995361+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2021-12-06T10:07:14.995376+00:00 app[web.1]: > projbackend@1.0.0 start /app
    2021-12-06T10:07:14.995377+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon app.js
    2021-12-06T10:07:14.995377+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2021-12-06T10:07:15.539554+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.19.4
    2021-12-06T10:07:15.540385+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    2021-12-06T10:07:15.541878+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
    2021-12-06T10:07:15.543473+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    2021-12-06T10:07:15.543944+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
    2021-12-06T10:07:17.214186+00:00 app[web.1]: App is running at 7000
    2021-12-06T10:07:17.326823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2021-12-06T10:07:17.533441+00:00 app[web.1]: DB CONNECTED
```

Everything is working fine in local machine which I deployed this application, but facing issue on other devices.
Please help me in finding the error for this cause. Thankyou in Advance!!

Comment: Cors might be causing this. Can you remove all Cors lines and try again?

Comment: @Abdulhakim Getting this error **Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:7000/api/products' from origin 'https://shop-spot.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.** 
even in my local machine, but working fine on localhost

Answer (score 1):

I figured that out, My issue is resolved after adding heroku postbuild scripts into my main package.json file.